# 'cut' like feature for Windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

It's been a while since I've done Windows batch files, and I seem to have forgotten everything.  What I want to do is look for services where the path has spaces but the string isn't quoted.  Boy, this would be easy with bash, but...

So, in a nutshell, I start with `sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME` and dump that to a temp file.  Then I read it back in to a variable with `for /F "tokens=2" %%f in (temp_file) do set services=!services! %%f`  That gets me a variable with a space-delimited list of all services on my host.  Now, in a FOR loop against that variable, I run  `sc qc %%s | findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME` and dump THAT to a temp file.  It winds up containing something like (quotes are mine to preserve all the spaces):

```
"       BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted"
```

I've been reading and Googling and testing and trying everything, trying to wind up cutting that output at the `:` so I can just wind up with the path itself, and then start figuring out the abomination that must be regular expressions under Windows.  But I just cannot get that string split.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following if you want the binary path for all services:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%n in ('sc query ^| findstr SERVICE_NAME') do (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%r in (
    'sc qc "%%~n" ^| findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME'
  ) do (
    echo %%~s
  )
)
```

Change `echo %%~s` to `echo %%~n:%%~s` if you want the binary path prepended with the name of the service.

Comment: Note that `for /f` is awful in the presence of spaces. You can use `tokens=2*` to match the 2nd and all subsequent tokens, but each gets assigned a new variable; in this case `%n`, `%m`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ansgar Wiechers has a good solution using SC to get the info for running services. It also demonstrates how to use the FOR /F delims option to break at the `:`.

Another option is to use WMIC to get the same information in a more direct manner.

If all you want is a list of binary paths for all active (running) services, then all you need is:

```
wmic service where "state='Running'" get pathname
```

If you want the list of service names as well as the binary paths:

```
wmic service where "state='Running'" get name, pathname
```

There are many more properties that can be listed. Type `wmic service get /?` from the command prompt to get a complete list.

If you want to get the values into variables within a batch process so that you can take action, then a FOR /F loop is used. I append the state property at the end to avoid an odd FOR /F quirk that appends an unwanted `<CR>` to the end of each line of WMIC output. The unwanted `<CR>` will be attached to the state value, which we don't care about. I also use the state with FINDSTR to weed out unwanted lines, so there is no need for the WMIC WHERE clause. In this example I simply echo the values, but obviously you could do whatever is needed with them.

```
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%A in (
  '"wmic service get name, pathname, state /format:csv|findstr /e Running"'
) do echo %%A: %%B
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('sc query ^| findstr SERVICE_NAME') do (
   sc qc %%a | findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME
)
pause
```